# change the default "more' image for the options menu when i have 6 menus

Tags: android, menu

i want to  change the default "more' image for the options menu  when i have 6 menus,i can modifu the frist 5 menu by :

```
menu.add(MENU_GROUP_HOMESCREEN, MENU_WALLPAPER_SETTINGS, 0,  R.string.menu_wallpaper)
             .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
             .setAlphabeticShortcut('W');
```

but the 6th menu .i donot know how to modify its icon,it used the defualt icon
how to modify it .i used :

menu.findItem(6) or
  menu.getItem(6).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
but no effect,can you give me info.thank you

Comment: Not enough information, where you are working, need to see the menu being built.

Comment: thank you for your answer,my app is common app,because i modify 5 menus icon ,the default icon not good  as others,so i want to modify it

Comment: @pengwang, I have the same issue !! any luck ?

Comment: no,at present i have to only have 6 menu,other menus i put to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know whether this will help you or not, but one possible way is to make custom "More" button e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item ...
        ... />
    <item ...
        ... />
    <item ...
        ... />
    <item ...
        ... />
    <item ...
        ... />  

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_more"
    android:title="More" 
    android:icon="your_custom_icon">
       <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item ...
                ... />
            ...
            ...
            <item ...
                ... /> 
       </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: I have not tried it, but this should work. However, this approach will work only when you know your menu count at compile time. In my case, I have to think some other way, because some of my menu items would be added at run time e.g by sub-activity or fragment.

Comment: just remove xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    from second <menu> tag and It works fine